# Recovering saved server.js file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I was completing my server.js file on visual studio code. It hanged at the last minute and when I forced restarted the laptop, the server.js file was completely empty. My file was being saved by the autoSave option in VS code.

I am using Linux.

Comment: why not save it once in a while your typing? You don't save for hours?

Comment: no i wasn't using git that's why i am worried about recovering it

Comment: I have used [recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) in the past to recover deleted files. But deletion recovery is never guaranteed to work. Because the Operating Systems decide the fate of deleted files.